# How to install tofrodos in Yosemite via Homebrew?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

This thread is based on my attempt to parse windows syntax to unix in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165336/16920).
I run successfully `brew reinstall tofrodos` and get

```
==> Reinstalling tofrodos
==> Downloading http://tofrodos.sourceforge.net/download/tofrodos-1.7.13.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tofrodos-1.7.13.tar.gz
==> make
  /usr/local/Cellar/tofrodos/1.7.13: 5 files, 80K, built in 2 seconds
```

I run `hash -r; tofrodos --help` and get

```
-bash: tofrodos: command not found
```

Also no manual existing: `man tofrodos` gives

```
No manual entry for tofrodos
```

**How can you use this tofrodos command?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tofrodos` package doesn't have a `tofrodos` command line tool. It provides two command line tools: `fromdos` and `todos`. You can see them in the package directory after Homebrew installs the package locally:

```
IanCsiMac:~ |ruby-2.1.2|
> ls /usr/local/Cellar/tofrodos/1.7.13
COPYING              INSTALL_RECEIPT.json bin                  readme.txt           share

IanCsiMac:~ |ruby-2.1.2|
> ls /usr/local/Cellar/tofrodos/1.7.13/bin
fromdos todos

IanCsiMac:~ |ruby-2.1.2|
> which fromdos
/usr/local/bin/fromdos

IanCsiMac:~ |ruby-2.1.2|
> which todos
/usr/local/bin/todos
```

You need to look for `fromdos` and `todos` in your `PATH`, not `tofrodos` -- there is no `tofrodos` command. Similarly, the `man` pages are for those commands, not `tofrodos`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it is a bad practice to put two unrelated commands in one package like this. Next time I just do *brew info [command]; ls [some-path]/readme" and look for -exe or different executable files which are assumed to be commandline commands.

Comment: The commands *are* related -- they use a shared library to do OS line ending translation on files. It's very common to package multiple, related commands in to a package like this -- has been as long as I've been a *nix user now...some 25 years now. But really, if you have a problem with what tofrodos contains, you're welcome to submit a patch that breaks the package up: http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/